# If $x \notin \operatorname{Supp}(D)$, then $j_x^{*}(D) = 0$, where $j_x : \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to X$ is the canonical morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a non-empty noetherian scheme, which is a absolute curve ; i.e., a non-empty noetherian scheme with irreducible components $X_i  (1 \le i \le n )$ satisfying the following equivalent condition (Görtz's Algebraic Geometry, Prop.15.1)

> (i) For every closed point $x \in X$, $\operatorname{dim} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}=1$  ( i.e., $\operatorname{Codim}_x(\{x\})=1).$
> (ii) The closed irreducible subsets of $X$ are the $X_i$ and the closed points of $X$.
> (iii) The scheme $X$ is of pure dimension $1$ ( i.e., $\operatorname{dim}X_i =1$ for all $i$).

If $D$ is a cartier divisor of $X$, then its support is defined by

$$ \operatorname{Supp}(D):= \{x \in X : D_{x} \neq 1 \}$$

where $D_{x}$ denotes the image of $D \in  \Gamma({X, \mathcal{K}_X^{\times}/\mathcal{O}_X^{\times}})$ in the stalk $(\mathcal{K}_X^{\times}/\mathcal{O}_X^{\times})_x$. In other words, if $D$ is represented by $(U_i, f_i)$, then a point $x\in X$ lies in $\operatorname{Supp}(D)$ if and only if $(f_i)_x\notin \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times}$ for all (or, equivalently, for one) index $i$ with $x \in U_i$. (Görtz's book p. 305)

Now fix $x\in X$ such that $\operatorname{dim}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=1$ and a divisor $D$ on X. Let $j_x : \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to X$ be the canonical morphism.

**My question is**, **if $ x\notin \operatorname{Supp}(D)$, then $j_{x}^{*}(D) = 0$?** Here, $j_x^{*}(D)$ is the inverse image (or pull-back) of $D$ defined as follows:

> Let $ f : X \to Y $ be a morphism of schemes. Assume that the homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$ given by $f$ extends to a homomorphism $\mathcal{K}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{K}_X$.
> Then we obtain a homomorphism $\mathcal{K}_Y^{\times}/ \mathcal{O}_{Y}^{\times}\to f_{*}\mathcal{K}_X^{\times}/ f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\times}\to f_{*}(\mathcal{K}_X^{\times}/ \mathcal{O}_{X}^{\times})$, and hence we have a homomorphism between cartier divisors:

$$ f^{*} : \operatorname{Div}(Y) = \Gamma{(Y, \mathcal{K}_Y^{\times}}/\mathcal{O}_{Y}^{\times}) \to \Gamma{(X,\mathcal{K}_X^{\times}}/\mathcal{O}_X^{\times})=\operatorname{Div}(X),$$

called the pullback (c.f. Görtz's book, p. 312). Maybe we can describe this homomorphism more concretely as follows : Let $D \in \operatorname{Div}(Y)$ be represented by $(U_i, f_i)_i$. Then $f^{*}(D)$ is represented by $(f^{-1}(U_i), \bar{f^{\flat}}_{U_i} (f_i))_i$, where $\bar{f^{\flat}} : \mathcal{K}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{K}_X$ is the extended homomorphism of the $f^{\flat} : \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X}$.

**My first attempt to our question** : Let $D := (U_i, f_i)_i$ be a cartier divisor on $X$ and $x\in \operatorname{Supp}(D)$. Then $(f_i)_x\in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times}$ for some index $i$ with $x \in U_i$.

We want to show that $j_x^{*}(D) = (j_x^{-1}(U_i), \bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{, U_i}(f_i))_i = 0$ in $\operatorname{Div}(\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$. Note that $(j_x^{-1}(U_i), 1)_i$ forms a zero element of $\operatorname{Div}(\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ (true?).

Note that for two divisors $E$ and $F$ given by $(U_i, f_i)_i$ and $(V_j, g_j)_j$, $E=F$ if and only if
$f_ig_j^{-1} \in \Gamma(U_i \cap V_j, \mathcal{O}_X^{\times})$ for all $i, j$.

So, to show that $j_x^{*}(D) = 0$, it suffices to show that for all $i$, $\bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{, U_i}(f_i) \in  \Gamma(j_x^{-1}(U_i), \mathcal{O}^{\times}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}})$

i.e., we want to show that

$$ (f_i)_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times} \operatorname{for all} i \operatorname{with} x \in U_i  \Rightarrow \bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{, U_i}(f_i) \in  \Gamma(j_x^{-1}(U_i), \mathcal{O}^{\times}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}) \operatorname{for all} i $$

Here, I explain the statement "$(f_i)_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times}$" in greater detail. It means that $(f_i)_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times}$ up to the injective homomorphism $\iota_{X,x} : \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \mathcal{K}_{X,x}$, where $\iota_X : \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{K}_X$ may be defined as follows: Fix an open $U \subset X$. Then

$$ \iota_{X, U} : \mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{K}_X(U):= \{(s_x)\in \prod_{x\in U}\mathcal{K}'_{X,x} : -- \} = \{(s_x)\in \prod_{x\in U}\operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) :-- \}$$

$$ s \mapsto  \frac{[(U,s)]_{x \in U}}{1}$$

(where the second equality for $\mathcal{K}_X(U)$ is true because $X$ is noetherian (c.f. Liu's Algebraic Geometry, p. 255, Lemma 1.12-(c)).

($\iota_X$ is injective? c.f. Görtz's p. 300).

Similarly, the statement "$\bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{, U_i}(f_i) \in  \Gamma(j_x^{-1}(U_i), \mathcal{O}^{\times}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}})$" means that it is upto injective(?) homomorphism

$j_{x,*}(\iota_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}) : j_{x,*}\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \to j_{x,*}\mathcal{K}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}$.

And this is point that I stuck. How to extract some information from
$(f_i)_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times}$ for some $i$ with $x\in U_i$ to show
$\bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{, U_i}(f_i) \in  \Gamma(j_x^{-1}(U_i), \mathcal{O}^{\times}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}})$ for all $i$ ?

To this, I tried to describe the extended homomorphism $\bar{j_x^{\flat}} : \mathcal{K}_X \to j_{x,*} \mathcal{K}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}$ from $j_x^{\flat} : \mathcal{O}_X \to j_{x,*}\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}$ more concretely.

For example, for
$(s_x)_{x\in U} \in \mathcal{K}_X(U)$, by the above description for $\mathcal{K}_X(U)$, we can write $(s_x)_{x\in U}=(\frac{a_x}{r_x})_{x\in U}$ where $a_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and $r_x$ is a regular element of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$(true?). Then how to send $(s_x)_{x\in U}$ to an element of $(j_{x,*}\mathcal{K}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}})(U) = \{(l_y)\in \prod_{y\in j_x^{-1}(U)}\operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}),y)}) : -- \} $?

Can anyone present explicit description? (Or how to prove our desired question?)

**Furthur progress** : Through some investigation, It seems that key point is that the canonical homomorphism $j_x : \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to X$ is a homeomorphism from $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ onto the subspace $Z$ which is the intersection of all open subsets of $X$ which contain $x$.(c.f. Gortz, p.69) Let me argue furthur progress.

Let $D : = (U_j,f_j)_j$ be a cartier divisor on $X$ and fix $x \notin \operatorname{Supp}(D)$. Then by the Gortz, p.305, $(f_i)_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times}$ for some $i \in I$ with $x \in U_i$. More precisely, $(f_i)_x \in \iota_{X,x}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times})$, where $\iota : \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{K}_X$ is the injection (c.f. above description).
So there exists $[(U,s)] \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times}$ such that

$$ [(U_i, f_i)] = [ (U, \frac{[(U,s)]_{x\in U}}{1})]$$

Write $(f_i) \in \mathcal{K}_X(U_i)$ as $(t_x)_{x\in U_i} \in \prod_{x\in U_i}\operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$. Then the above equality means that there exists an open neighborhood $W \subset U_i \cap U$ which contains $x$ and such that

$$(t_x)_{x\in W} = (t_x)_{x\in U_i}|_W = \frac{[(U,s)]_{x\in U}}{1}|_W = \frac{[(U,s)]_{x\in W}}{1}$$

**Now, let $Y:= \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.**

Note that the canonical morphism $j_x : Y \to X$ is a homeomorphism onto the subspace of intersection of all open subsets of $X$ which contain $x$.
So, $Y=j_x^{-1}(U_i)= j_x^{-1}(W)$ and $(j_x^{-1}(W),1)$ forms a zero element of $\operatorname{Div}(Y)$ and $j_x^{*}(D):=(j_x^{-1}(U_j),\bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,U_j}(f_j))_j = (j_x^{-1}(U_i), \bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,U_i}(f_i))$ !.  where $\bar{j_x^{\flat}} : \mathcal{K}_X \to j_{x,*}\mathcal{K}_Y$ is the extension of $j_x^{\flat}$.

(True? C.f. definition of cartier divisor and note that for two divisors $E$ and $F$ given by $(U_i, f_i)_i$ and $(V_j, g_j)_j$, $E=F$ if and only if
$f_ig_j^{-1} \in \Gamma(U_i \cap V_j, \mathcal{O}_X^{\times})$ for all $i, j$.).

So, since $j_x^{-1}(W) \subset j_x^{-1}(U_i)$, to show $j_x^{*}(D)=0$, it suffices to show that

$$ \bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,U_i}(f_i)|_{j_x^{-1}(W)} \in \mathcal{O}_Y(j_x^{-1}(W))^{\times} $$.

More precisely, $ \bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,U_i}(f_i)|_{j_x^{-1}(W)} \in j_{x,*}(\iota_Y)_W(\mathcal{O}_Y(j_x^{-1}(W))^{\times}) $, where $\iota_Y : \mathcal{O}_Y \to \mathcal{K}_Y$ is the injection.

Since $\bar{j_x^{\flat}}$ is natural transformation, $\bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,U_i}(f_i) | _{j_x^{-1}(W)} = \bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,W}(f_i |_W)$. So it suffices to show that $\bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,W}(f_i |_W) \in j_{x,*}(\iota_Y)_W(\mathcal{O}_Y(j_x^{-1}(W))^{\times})$. It means that there exists $t \in \mathcal{O}_Y(j_x^{-1}(W))^{\times}$ such that

$$\bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,W}(f_i|_W)= j_{x,*}(\iota_Y)_{W}(t) = \frac{[(j_x^{-1}(W),t)]_{y\in j_x^{-1}(W)}}{1}$$.

But note that we have a commutative diagram :

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{K}_X(W) @>{\bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{, W}}>> \mathcal{K}_Y(j_x^{-1}(W))\\
@A{\iota_{X,W}}AA @AA {j_{x,*}(\iota_Y)_{W}}A \\
\mathcal{O}_{X}(W) @>{j^{\flat}_{x,W}}>> \mathcal{O}_Y(j_x^{-1}(W))
\end{CD}$$

So, for the $s \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ above, we have

$$\bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,W} \circ \iota_{X,W} (s|_W) = j_{x,*}(\iota_Y)_W \circ j_{x ,W}^{\flat}(s|_W)$$

$$ \Rightarrow \bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,W}( \frac{[(W,s|_W)]_{x\in W}}{1}) = \frac{[(j_x^{-1}(W), j_{x,W}^{\flat}(s|_W))]_{y \in j_x^{-1}(W)}}{1} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,W}( \frac{[(U,s)]_{x\in W}}{1}) = \frac{[(j_x^{-1}(W), j_{x,W}^{\flat}(s|_W))]_{y \in j_x^{-1}(W)}}{1} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,W}(f_i|_W) := \bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{,W}((t_x)_{x\in W}) = \frac{[(j_x^{-1}(W), j_{x,W}^{\flat}(s|_W))]_{y \in j_x^{-1}(W)}}{1} $$

So, if $s\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)^{\times}$, then $j_{x,W}^{\flat}(s|_W)) \in \mathcal{O}_Y(j_x^{-1}(W))^{\times}$ and we are done.

And this is point that I stuck. We have that $[(U,s)] \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times}$. My question is, furthurmore can we take $s$ as
$s\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)^{\times}$ ?

Comment: Doesn't $\bar{j_x^{\flat}}_{, U_i}(f_i) \in  \Gamma(j_x^{-1}(U_i), \mathcal{O}^{\times}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}})$ mean that you have a unit in a local ring and isn't $(f_i)_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times}$ the same element in the same local ring just in different notation? Correct me if I'm wrong. You are doing the right thing following the many layers of definitions that make modern algebraic geometry such a daunting subject.

Comment: Uhm..some ambiguity. Can you make more formal or clear about what are you trying to say? I'm confused in interpreting your comment. For example, as a local ring, which ring you indicating? I agree with your final feeling too :)

Comment: $\Gamma(j_x^{-1}(U_i), \mathcal{O}^{\times}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}})$ are sections of a sheaf of rings and I claim they have the structure of a local ring. $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times}$ is a [stalk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalk_(sheaf)) of a sheaf of rings and thus a ring, I claim it is a local ring. Even further: These two local rings should not just be isomorphic but equal, since the elements get pushed and pulled around between these two objects, but stay unchanged and still form the same underlaying set and the same underlying ring. Am I wrong?

Comment: O.K. I understand your overall strategy. And now for me it is hard to follow your argument : in particular, "since the elements get pushed and pulled around between these two object bla bla~~" ;i.e., do you believe that we can make formal proof of $\Gamma(j_x^{-1}(U_i), \mathcal{O}^{\times}_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}) = \mathcal{O}^{\times}_{X,x}$ ? And $\bar{j^{\flat}_{x}}_{, U_i}(f_i) = (f_i)_{x}$ in this case? Anyway It seems that some further investigation is necessary.

Comment: @Thomas Preu : Uhm.. I upload furthur my own progress. Perhaps, this maybe helps you  or maybe stimulus  to our discussion. Can you see?